# Flink Standalone K8 - Cannot create HA service - NullPointerException

Tags: apache-flink

I currently have a Flink (1.12) cluster running in Standalone Kubernetes (v1.16).
For our purposes, we have went with an `application cluster` mode deployment.

To make our flink cluster more resilient to failures we want to add HA to our current setup, and I have gone through the documentation and followed the example configurations recommended for our given setup ([here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#high-availability-with-standalone-kubernetes)).

flink-conf.yaml

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: {{ $fullName }}-jobmanager
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 1600m
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1728m
    blob.server.port: 6124
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    parallelism.default: 2
    scheduler-mode: reactive
    execution.checkpointing.interval: 10s 
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.cluster-id: thoros-cluster-1
    high-availability.storageDir: s3:///company-flink-{{ .Values.environment }}/recovery
```

job.yaml (excerpt)

```
...
restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: jobmanager
          image: "{{ .Values.thoros.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ default "Always" .Values.thoros.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                apiVersion: v1
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
          # The following args overwrite the value of jobmanager.rpc.address configured in the configuration config map to POD_IP.
          args: [
              "standalone-job",
              "--host",
              "$(POD_IP)",
              "--job-classname",
              "com.company.beam.Main"]
```

There are of course a couple of other configurations I am leaving out (happy to provide those if needed)

To test, I have set the Job parallelism to 2 (which spins up two JobManagers, one of which should be standby)

When trying to deploy this to K8 the JobManager pods fail immediately with the following error - I am not sure what may be missing here aside from the fact that something seems to be missing hence causing the `Nullpointerexception`?

```
2021-08-20 12:06:55,133 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Initializing cluster services.
2021-08-20 12:06:55,176 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Trying to start actor system, external address 100.107.0.5:6123, bind address 0.0.0.0:6123.
2021-08-20 12:06:56,956 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                 [] - Slf4jLogger started
2021-08-20 12:06:57,067 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                         [] - Starting remoting
2021-08-20 12:06:57,469 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                         [] - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@100.107.0.5:6123]
2021-08-20 12:06:57,687 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcServiceUtils        [] - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@100.107.0.5:6123
2021-08-20 12:06:58,671 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint down with application status FAILED. Diagnostics org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the ha services from the instantiated HighAvailabilityServicesFactory org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createCustomHAServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:124)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.createHaServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:338)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:296)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:175)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:585)
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.main(StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.<init>(Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.FlinkKubeClientFactory.fromConfiguration(FlinkKubeClientFactory.java:106)q
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory.createHAServices(KubernetesHaServicesFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createCustomHAServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:265)
    ... 9 more
.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,684 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopping Akka RPC service.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,754 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,767 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,833 INFO  akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator        [] - Remoting shut down.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,882 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Stopped Akka RPC service.
2021-08-20 12:06:58,882 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Could not start cluster entrypoint StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointException: Failed to initialize the cluster entrypoint StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:201) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:585) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.container.entrypoint.StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.main(StandaloneApplicationClusterEntryPoint.java:85) [flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not create the ha services from the instantiated HighAvailabilityServicesFactory org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createCustomHAServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:268) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:124) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.createHaServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:338) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:296) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:224) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:178) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:175) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.<init>(Fabric8FlinkKubeClient.java:85) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.FlinkKubeClientFactory.fromConfiguration(FlinkKubeClientFactory.java:106) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory.createHAServices(KubernetesHaServicesFactory.java:37) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createCustomHAServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:265) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.highavailability.HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.createHighAvailabilityServices(HighAvailabilityServicesUtils.java:124) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.createHaServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:338) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.initializeServices(ClusterEntrypoint.java:296) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:224) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.lambda$startCluster$1(ClusterEntrypoint.java:178) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:175) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.5.jar:1.12.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to using `high-availability.cluster-id` when it should be `kubernetes.cluster-id`.